# List all registered users in a tabel with checkboxlist servercontrol

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm making a newsletter function, and I would like to list all registered users with name, surname and email in a table (backend), so the administrator can choose who he will send a newsletter to. I have tried using checkbox server control and I've tried to make the table in code behind; the database and all that are working fine.

Here is the code I'm using:

ASP.NET,

```
<asp:CheckBoxList 
    ID="cblNyhedsBrev"
    CssClass="cblNyhedsbrev"
      RepeatDirection="Vertical" 
    runat="server">
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Codebehind:

```
foreach (DataRow hentmailliste in HentMails.HentMailListe().Rows)
{
    litHentMails.Text = hentmailliste["fldNavn"].ToString();
    litHentMails.Text += hentmailliste["fldEfternavn"].ToString();
    cblNyhedsBrev.Items.Add(new ListItem(hentmailliste["fldMail"].ToString())); 
                                         //hentmailliste[""].ToString() +
                                         //hentmailliste[""].ToString()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Entitify Framework and LINQ to pull the list of names,surnames and email address from the database and bind LINQ results to gridview control.

```
using (var ltr= new NewsLetterEntities()){ 
var results = ltr.Recepients.ToList();
}

newsLetterGrid.Datasource=results;
newsLetterGrid.Databind();
```

Add checkbox button to gridview itemtemplate section.

In the Save or Email event(which ever one you have to send an email) loop through gridview rows and see if checkbox is checked or not. Use gridview `findControl` to get the checkbox control:

```
CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)newsLetterGrid.FindControl("chkMyCheckBox");
if(chk.checked){ //extract email address from row and concatenate to emailString }
```

Concatenate all your emails results and add them to your sendEmail function.